# Collision with fixed pixel-size items on QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, collision, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I'm using Qt's GraphicsView/GraphicsScene framework, and I have to draw some line items.

To be sure these items are always visible (independant of the zoom level) I use a cosmetic pen, with a size of 3 (for example) so I always get lines of 3 pixels width drawn on screen.

But these items doesn't receive mouse events (such as hoverEnterEvent/hoverLeaveEvent) when I'm zooming out a lot.

I've digged in the code, and it appears that all collisions tests are done with the return value of the shape() function.

So I've tried to re-implement "shape()" and also "contains()" and "collidesWithPath()" methods, but I still have problems to detect collisions (because when zoom is changed, I need to re-update the shape for example).

Is there any tricks to do that ?

In an efficient way ? (without re-updating the item's shape at every zoom change)

Thanks

Comment: *" all collisions tests are done with the return value of the shape() function"* Not quite true, the boundingRect is also used. It would be useful if you could show an [example of the problem, with code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're asking why some code doesn't work, but you don't provide the code. This question will be closed unless you edit it with a minimal, self-contained example that reproduces it.

Comment: I did'nt included any code because in my opinion, this question is more general than about debugging an erroneous code.

To make it simple, "How to get/create/use view resolution dependant shape" ?

I don't ask about code, but about the main idea : should I update my item's shape at every view scale change (seems slow) ? Should I reimplement the collision detection code to be view dependant (seems difficult) ? Is there any other way ?

Thanks

Comment: If you implement the zoom using QGraphicsView.setTransform() function, you do not have to update the shape() or boundingRect() function because the item transform w.r.t. to scene remains unchanged. Or are you asking about something else?